# Javascriptのスライダーの初期値について

Tags: javascript, html

私はいまjavascriptで、fontsizeを変更するスライダーを実装しているのですが、
ページを開いたとき、実際のサイズと、スライダー上の値が異なっています。

inputのvalueで設定しているように、javascriptの初期値valueも10にしたいです。
（表示されるフォントのサイズは10pxなのですが）、スライダーでは中心に位置しています。

ページを開くと、一度スライダーのトグルが10付近に位置するのですが、すぐに中心に戻ります。
ですので、javascriptのvalueが優先されていると考えました。
こちらのjavascriptのvalueの設定方法をお教えいただきたいです。

※CSSではfontsizeに関して設定していません。

```
<li><span class="filter-type">font-size</span>
<input type="range" name="fontsize" id="slider0" min="1" max="50" value="10" onchange="changeFontSize()"></li>

<div class=\"texts\" id=\"fontstyle\">テキスト</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeFontSize() {             
                var size = document.getElementById('slider0').value;
                document.getElementById('fontstyle').style.fontSize = size + 'px';
            }
</script>
```

このinput type="range"の値を、GET送信したいので、あまりHTMLの形は変えたくありません。
しかし、変更しても送信できるような方法をご存知の方も、ご教授いただけたらと思っております。

お願い致します。

Comment: `\"texts\" id=\"fontstyle\"` の部分なぜエスケープしているのかわかりません。単純に`"texts" id="fontstyle"` でよいと思います。それ以外は別段問題無いように思います。フォントサイズを`value`と合わせるためには単に`changeFontSize()`を最初に一度呼びだせばいいだけのように思います。「スライダーが中央に戻ってしまう。」については再現しませんでした。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
phpファイル上でechoしているのでエスケープしています。質問用に正すのを見落としました...。
以下のようにしたら、10に設定はされませんでしたが、逆にスライダーのトグル位置通りにfontsizeが設定されました！ありがとうございます！
（実はfontweightもありました）

`window.onload = function() {
 changeFontSize();
 changeFontWeight();
}
function changeFontSize() {
 var size = document.getElementById('slider0').value;
 document.getElementById('fontstyle').style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
function changeFontWeight() {
 var weight = document.getElementById('slider1').value; 
 document.getElementById('fontstyle').style.fontWeight = weight;
}`